# how to update firebase table adding hashmap without overriding

Tags: android, firebase, real-time

i have this fireBase project that integrated with storage  and realtime database

**what i want to accomplish is:**

1- run the pushreport() Method that adding data to DB ;
2 - add an image to storage ;

3 - update the same report node created with imgurl

**here is my push to database Method**

```
 private String keytocurrentReport =   "" ;

private void pushReport() {

    //1: report Object
    reportValues.put("type", KEY_REPORT_TYPE);
    reportValues.put("reportId", KEY_REPORT_ID);

    //2 : key pushed

    keytocurrentReport = dbInstance.getReference().child("Reports").push().getKey();

    //3: children updates
    Map<String, Object> childUpdates = new HashMap<>();

    childUpdates.put("Reports/" + keytocurrentReport + "/", reportValues);

    dbInstance.getReference().updateChildren(childUpdates).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {

        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {

           /* // TODO: 8/29/2017 show Snack Bar Or Dialog
            if (ActivtyIsShowing) {
                AppUtils.startActivityClearStack(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), ActivityMain.class);
                hideProgressDialog();
            }*/

            Log.d(TAG , "reported pushed") ;
            Log.d(TAG , "key = " + keytocurrentReport);
            Toast.makeText(MyApplication.getAppContext(), getResources().getString(R.string.report_sent), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });

}
```

**and here is my upload to storage Method :**

```
private void uploadImageToStorage(Context ctx) {

    String imageName = "report-" + new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyy_HHmmss").format(new java.util.Date());
    String pathRefToStoreImage = "Public/Reports/" + uid + "/images/" + imageName + ".png";
    StorageReference stoargeRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference(pathRefToStoreImage);  // is the main hook*//*



    UploadTask uploadTask = stoargeRef.putBytes(AppUtils.bitmapToByte(bmReport));
    uploadTask.addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                Log.d(TAG , "task uploading image complete ") ;

                String stImage = task.getResult().getDownloadUrl().toString();

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext() , "task ok  " , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                HashMap<String , Object > map = new HashMap<String, Object>( ) ;
                map.put("imgURl " ,stImage ) ;

                pushtoTable(map , "pathtochange");

                //todo hrm to push to Report table
                //image upladed go and uplad vi

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), getResources().getString(R.string.network_error), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.d(TAG, "unable to upload image to db" + task.getException());
            }
        }
    });
}
```

**and here is update table method :**

```
private void pushtoTable(HashMap<String , Object> values , String ptath){

    Log.d(TAG , "pushtoTable") ;
    Map<String, Object> childUpdates = new HashMap<>();
    childUpdates.put("Reports/" + keytocurrentReport, values);

    dbInstance.getReference().updateChildren(childUpdates).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {

        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
            Log.d(TAG , "completed +" + task.getResult() ) ;
```

/*

```
            // TODO: 8/29/2017 show Snack Bar Or Dialog
            if (ActivtyIsShowing) {
                AppUtils.startActivityClearStack(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), ActivityMain.class);
                hideProgressDialog();
            }

            Toast.makeText(MyApplication.getAppContext(), getResources().getString(R.string.report_sent), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

*/
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext()  , "reports updated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

```
        }
    });
}
```

**The Proplem is : the values in the node get Overriding with the new hashmap 
so how can i acomplish this  ?**

Comment: How about actually reading the basic firebase guide?

Answer (score 0):

Use Push()

```
final YourObject  object = new YourObject();
        object .setTitle(objectTitleString);
        object .setDate(objectDateString);
        mFirebaseref .child("your Where you want to update).push().setValue(object);
```

Create a model Class

```
public class YourObject implements Serializable {

private String mTitle;
private String mDate;

/*Object Model to get and set news data*/
public String getNewsTitle() {
return mTitle;

public String getmDate(String date)
return mDate
}

public void setmTitle() {
this.mTitle = title;
}
 ...
```